# SQL count show group by show in column instead of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this
[image]

Now my output would like to be

```
total_rows | completed | incomplete
------------------------------------
7              2            5
```

How can I achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use condition aggregation

```
select count(*) total ,
      sum(completed = 1) completed , 
      sum(completed = 0) incompleted 
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
select
    count(*) as total_rows,
    sum(case when completed = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as completed,
    sum(case when completed = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as incomplete
from myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select
  count(*) as total_rows,
  sum(completed) completed,
  sum(1 - completed) incomplete
from tablename
```

or:

```
select
  count(*) as total_rows,
  sum(completed) completed,
  sum(not completed) incomplete
from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you

```
   select count(id) as total_rows , 
     sum(completed = 1) as completed , 
         sum(completed = 0) as incompleted from sales_call_task_jo_iformation;
```

please try this if you need I will help you